# Odoo 10 website embed video

Tags: html, xml, video, web, odoo

I'd like to add a embed video or background video to my odoo website.
I'd tried the default by adding a picture then switching it to video, but here you can only upload youtube videos etc.

This is not what I want, I want a clean video playing auto without any controls.

I tried following in a qweb/xml snippet but no video was shown...

```
<video id="myVideo">
     <source src="/website_custom/static/src/video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML5 could work, see the link for instructions:
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp
Please remember to enter a full path to the video. Otherwise, Odoo won't load it.